# article get wrong categories in eloquent laravel 5.5

Tags: mysql, orm, laravel-5.5, eloquent

I got stuck in my code where I get wrong category in my article, for detail I will show my code,

```
Artikel model

    class Artikel extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'judul', 'kutipan', 'slug', 'kategori_id','tag_id', 'isi', 'meta_keyword', 'meta_deskripsi', 'foto', 'status'
    ];

    protected $table = 'artikel';

    public function kategori(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Kategori','id');
    }
}
```

and this my Kategori model

```
protected $fillable = ['nama_kategori', 'slug'];
protected $table = 'kategori';

public function tag()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Tag','kategori_id');
}

public function artikel()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Artikel','kategori_id');
}
```

and when I try this on php artisan tinker

> Artikel::with('kategori')->where('slug','coba123')->get();

the result get wrong like this,

[image]

has anyone can help me? this make me confuse, I also have googling but still not change the result..

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong column:

```php
public function kategori(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Kategori','kategori_id');
}
```